How to read data installed in User1 from User 2 in multi user android
Using multi user, I created two user profile:
I have two apps. One is admin app and another is guest app.

User1 profile [Admin app installed]
User 2 profile[Guest app installed]

In admin app, I have simple edittext(username and age) and inserting the data.[User1]
Now i am switching to User2 and installing the guest app to read the inserted data from User1.
Actual Behaviour:
But problem is, I am not able to read the inserted data in User2.
Expected Behaviour:
I need to read the inserted data in User1 profile.
When I keep both app in same user profile[User1 profile], i can able to read the data.
Below is code snippet:
Admin:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout guestLayout;
    private EditText adminUsernameEditText, adminAgeEditText;
    private TextView displayTextView;
    private int guestCount = 0;
    private static final Uri SHARED_DATA_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.admin.guest.profile.provider/shared_data");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        guestLayout = findViewById(R.id.guestLayout);
        adminUsernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.adminUsernameEditText);
        adminAgeEditText = findViewById(R.id.adminAgeEditText);
        displayTextView = findViewById(R.id.displayTextView);

        Button adminButton = findViewById(R.id.adminButton);
        Button addGuestButton = findViewById(R.id.addGuestButton);

        adminButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveAdminData();
            }
        });

        addGuestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addGuestButton();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void saveAdminData() {
        String username = adminUsernameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String ageText = adminAgeEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (username.isEmpty()) {
            adminUsernameEditText.setError("Username cannot be empty");
            return;
        }

        if (ageText.isEmpty()) {
            adminAgeEditText.setError("Age cannot be empty");
            return;
        }

        int age;
        try {
            age = Integer.parseInt(ageText);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            adminAgeEditText.setError("Age must be a number");
            return;
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("username", username);
        values.put("age", age);

        getContentResolver().insert(SHARED_DATA_URI, values);
        displayTextView.setText("Admin data saved: Username - " + username + ", Age - " + age);
    }

    private void addGuestButton() {
        guestCount++;
        Button guestButton = new Button(this);
        guestButton.setText("Guest " + guestCount);
        guestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayAdminData();
            }
        });

        guestLayout.addView(guestButton);
    }

    private void displayAdminData() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        StringBuilder displayText = new StringBuilder("Admin Data:\n");

        try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(SHARED_DATA_URI, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    @SuppressLint("Range") String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"));
                    @SuppressLint("Range") int age = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("age"));
                    displayText.append("Username: ").append(username)
                            .append(", Age: ").append(age).append("\n");
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else {
                displayText.append("No data found.");
            }
        }

        displayTextView.setText(displayText.toString());
    }
}

I have successfully inserted data in Admin app for User 1 profile.
Below is the Guest app to read the inserted data in Admin app for User 2 profile.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView displayTextView;
    private static final Uri SHARED_DATA_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.admin.guest.profile.provider/shared_data");
    private static final String TAG = "GuestActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        displayTextView = findViewById(R.id.displayTextView);

        displayAdminData();
    }

    private void displayAdminData() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        StringBuilder displayText = new StringBuilder("Admin Data:\n");

        try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(SHARED_DATA_URI, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    @SuppressLint("Range") String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"));
                    @SuppressLint("Range") int age = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("age"));
                    displayText.append("Username: ").append(username)
                            .append(", Age: ").append(age).append("\n");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fetched data - Username: " + username + ", Age: " + age);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else {
                displayText.append("No data found.");
                Log.d(TAG, "No data found in ContentProvider.");
            }
        }

        displayTextView.setText(displayText.toString());
    }
}

Result:
Not able to read the data from User 1 profile.
In manifest, I gave this query for Android 12 but still I am not able to read.
 <queries>
        <!-- Query App 1's which is nothing but Admin package for accessing the content provider -->
        <package android:name="com.admin.guest.profile" />
    </queries>


"Not able to read the datas from User 1 profile" -- we have no idea what you mean by this. For example, does your app crash? If so, your question should include the stack trace. I have not worked very much with multi-user Android, but it would not surprise me if what you are seeking is not supported.

No crash. I am unable to read data in User 2 profile from User 1 profile.
